# run and execute text file using sqlite 3 command line

Tags: sqlite

I have a text file  which contains an sqlite statment where I want to dump it into .sql format but not able to excute it. Any help would be appreciated. My file is stored on desktop as verbali.txt and when i go to command prompt and to specific sqlite folder and run it just open the text file .

```
.mode insert 
.header on
.out file.sql 
select select Id   ,CompanyId  ,DateTime  ,Serial  ,DeviceId  ,AgentAId  ,GpsAddress  ,Targa  ,CommonRoadDescription  ,RoadCivicNumber  ,VehicleBrandDescription  ,VehicleModelDescription  ,VerbaliVehicleTypeDescription  ,CommonColorVehicleDescription  ,VerbaliRuleOneCode  ,VerbaliRuleOneDescription  ,VerbaliRuleOnePoints  ,VerbaliClosedNoteDescription  ,Points  ,VerbaliMissedNotificationDescription  ,MissedNotificationNote  ,StatementNote  from VerbaliData
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the file to sqlite3, in command prompt:

```
sqlite3 yourdatabase.db <path\to\verbali.txt
```

where `sqlite3` is the `sqlite3.exe` command line tool.

Comment: can you  tell me where i am going wrong. C:\programfiles<x86>\sqlite expert\personal 3> sqlitexpertpers.exe and then type in the following  right webmobility.db<c:\verbali.txt

Comment: when I try to run your command after the database it opens the sqlite database again I cant  find the file

Comment: is it possible to create a sql file from sqlite command prompt.